# RETURNING clause with BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: postgresql

I'm using table inheritance to split a table into smaller ones. I'm using `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to route new data into correct inherited tables. This trigger returns `NULL` so actual `INSERT` won't run on parent table.

The side effect of this is lack of any result of actual `INSERT`:

`INSERT INTO TABLE a VALUES (...) RETURNING a_id`

triggers `BEFORE INSERT` which directs new data to another table `a_CURRENT_DATE` - dynamically created when necessary by the trigger function. The trigger returns `NULL` so actual `INSERT` into table `a` is suppressed.

Original query has no result hence no `a_id` (`a_id` is a `SERIAL` column) is available.

What is the most elegant way to obtain `a_id` value?

Comment: I would use RULES for partitioning. unless you use some processing, then I would still stick to rules and add functions with logic to rule query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. That is typical problem with partitioning. I'm afraid there is no good, or elegant solution, and all you can do is to introduce some workarounds:

- inserting, and then deleting - yes, far from perfect,
- if you need `id` generated by `serial` type, you can use `currval()`... That would mean another query.

[Here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/INSERT_RETURNING_vs_Partitioning) there is yet another other way - you can create view, and use `instead of` trigger for that view. It is hard to tell if that is elegant, but for me that is quite close to that.

Comment: The `INSTEAD OF` solution is elegant enough for me

Comment: Using a view is really a smart idea.

Comment: For some people adding view is just introducing complexity. In the way that typical IT solution works - just add another abstraction layer. For me it solves my problem, but there is also something else. By providing view, you can later change structure of the tables, since client is not tightly coupled to them.